# How to insert database cell data into javascript alert

Tags: php, javascript, database

I have a simple form, when users submit the form, after successful validation, they get an alert

```
if (valid) {
    alert("Your Request Has Been Submitted")
} 
return valid;`
```

My goal is to have an auto incremental ticket number displayed in the javascript alert, I realize this can only happen after the data has been posted to the db, and that this can easily be done by sending the user to another page, but I'd like to have the page refreshed, and have an alert popup giving them a ticket number, then they can close the alert box and make another submission. Any assistance is appreciated. THANKS!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you start reading about [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp)

Comment: I'm trying to stick with PHP and JS only, but if anyone knows of a solution, I'm open to trying it.

Comment: I realize that but using AJAX would require me to add on to my WAMP stack which is not ideal (imo) Or at least I believe so, I could be completely wrong and it works by default

Comment: AJAX is quite possibly _also_ PHP and Javascript. Would do the job most splendidly. Submit the form through Javascript (that's what AJAX is) and then display the result through Javascript any way you want.

Comment: Just a thought.. but why would I want to use AJAX when the auto-incremental number I'm looking to place in my alert box, won't be assigned until after the data is submitted?

Comment: If you have a confirmation response from your ajax, it'll still work as the way you wanted..

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<script>
    var valid = <?php echo $query_result; ?>;
    if (valid) { alert("Your Request Has Been Submitted") }return valid;
</script>
```

Ensure that you PHP code echo'es a valid javascript for the value of the `valid` variable